# How to add suite into the kiwi-tcms

Tags: kiwi-tcms

How to change the kiwi-tcms's structure to the following:
Test plan-> Test Suite-> Test Case.
Now the test suite is not available. But I noticed that they had this functionality in 2017's release. Is there a plugin to add this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

> But I noticed that they had this functionality in 2017's

Very interesting. Where have you seen this? Kiwi TCMS has never had functionality to group test cases into suites which are then added to a test plan.

Comment: Probably a misunderstanding of change log items ->  v3.1.1-1 (Sep 8 2010) Completed feature #542660 - TCMS: [FEAT] - allow to add sub test suite for test plan 3.8.18.09 (Feb 28 2017, released on MrSenko.com) Enable the test suite. Fix #113 (Chenxiong Qi)

Comment: Yes. I've noticed this release (Feb 28 2017, released on MrSenko.com)

Comment: v3.1.1-1 is from 2010 before we got involved with the project and although it claims the same feature as you expect it doesn't seem to be present. It sounds like a usable feature so please open an feature request on GitHub.